# regex strip all digits except ordinals

Tags: ruby, regex

Looking for regex to use with #gsub in Ruby to strip all digits in a string except for ordinals. Assume the following is fine to preserve what I want in a string:

```
string = "100 red balloons"
strip_digits = string.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z\s]/, '')
=> " red balloons"
```

How would I go about modifying the regex in strip_digits such that if:

```
string = "50th red balloon"
```

strip_digits would return:

```
=> "50th red balloon"
```

That is, the regex would ignore digits that are part of ordinals, while matching them otherwise.

For this example, it's safe to assume that *any* string of digits immediately followed by an ordinal indicator ("nd", "th", "rd", or "st") is an ordinal.

Comment: So you want to remove everything in the second and the third lines?

Comment: If you just need to adjust your regex, you can use [`gsub(/(\d+(?:th|[rn]d|st))|[^a-z\s]/i, "\\1")`](http://ideone.com/XBHz3o)

Comment: How are you going to tell if a letter following a digit is part of an ordinal or something else? E.g., in `TP-Link TL-WR1043ND`.

Comment: @sawa  No, I don't want to remove the second and third lines. I want to modify the regex in the second line so that it will ignore digits ('50') that are part of an ordinal ('50th') while removing digits otherwise.  For my example, it's safe to assume that any occurrence of a digit(s) immediately followed by "nd", "st", or "th" is an ordinal.

Comment: Are the ordinal affixes that you care only those three?

Comment: @sawa....forgot about 'rd'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Thank you!  That's perfect.

Comment: @sarkon:Great, I posted with a bit of an explanation.

Comment: Do you want "22.3 degrees Celsius" to become ". degrees Celcius"? (Note the decimal point in the return string.) Can we assume that if a digit is immediately followed by a letter, that letter and the one after will be  "rd", "nd", "st", or "th"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland  That would be fine for this example,  just because I know that *any* string I'll be handling will be composed only of a-zA-Z0-9. I understand that the accepted answer does not solve the problem in full generality. But I tried to indicate my limited purposes in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a "fix" of your regex, I suggest:

```
input.gsub(/(\d+(?:th|[rn]d|st))|[^a-z\s]/i, "\\1")
```

See [IDEONE demo here](http://ideone.com/XBHz3o)

The logic is the following: match and capture into group 1 all the numbers followed with the ordinal numeral suffixes, and then restore this value with the `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern, and then match (to remove) all the non-letters and non-spaces with `[^a-z\s]` (or `[^\p{L}\s]`).

**Pattern details**:

- `(\d+(?:th|[rn]d|st))` - Group 1 matching 1+ digits (`\d+`) followed with either `th`, `rd`, `nd` or `st` (all substring is stored in a numbered buffer #1, that is accessed when the `\1` backreference is used in the replacement pattern)
- `|` - or
- `[^a-z\s]` - a character other than an ASCII letter (all lower- and uppercase letters are matched due to the `/i` case insensitive modifier) and a whitespace (to avoid removing Unicode letters, use `\p{L}` instead of `a-z`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`, i.e.:

```
strip_digits = string.gsub(/\b\d+(?!st|th|rd|nd)\b/, '')
```

---

**Regex explanation:**

```
\b\d+(?!st|th|rd|nd)\b

Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) «\b»
Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only) «\d+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!st|th|rd|nd)»
   Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «st»
      Match the character string “st” literally (case sensitive) «st»
   Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «th»
      Match the character string “th” literally (case sensitive) «th»
   Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «rd»
      Match the character string “rd” literally (case sensitive) «rd»
   Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «nd»
      Match the character string “nd” literally (case sensitive) «nd»
Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) «\b»
```

---

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qX5qD4/1)

Comment: The OP wrote "ordinals (including 'st' and 'nd' ordinals)", which implies that there are other affixes.

Comment: @sawa ***"For this example, it's safe to assume that any string of digits immediately followed by an ordinal indicator ("nd", "th", "rd", or "st") is an ordinal."***

Comment: You downvoted the answer without understanding the question.

Comment: @sawa: so he added the other affixes. other than that, it's exactly the same as it was. So why didn't you remove the downvote??? (it's cool I"ll do it for you)

Comment: oh ok. (you didn't deny it!) - either way, tis fixed, upvoted.

Comment: I added more ordinals (rd|nd) after the op updated the question. It would have been more helpful if you just mentioned the misding ordinals instead of simply downvote.

Comment: @Sweaver2112 appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead:  (this also collapses extra spaces)

```
 t = "And on 3rd day, he created the 1st of his 22 books, not including the 3 that were never published - this was the 2nd time this happened."
 print(t.gsub(/\s*\d+(?!st|th|rd|nd)\s*/, " "))#=>And on 3rd day, he created the 1st of his books, not including the that were never published - this was the 2nd time this happened.
```

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/twDY1I)